# Configuration setting for decode base64 string to image Mail server

Tags: image, base64, decode

In our application we are reading mail body which client have replied to our mail address and saved it to our database table.

When some clients reply on our email address mail body contains base64 string with header Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64.

Is there is any configuration setting on mail server that it will convert the base64 string into image?

This problem occurs only with some clients not all. I am guessing that these clients have base64 image in their signature.

Please check below image for what response we get in our application.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the server that needs to convert anything.  base64 encoded images are already images.

It is your client, whatever you are using to view the emails that needs to interpret the embedded base64 encoding and display it as an image to you.

Comment: #Lance thanks for the reply.means do we need to convert base64 string manually at our application?

Comment: Yes, that is it exactly.